# Create Bash Update Log

Tags: bash

I am trying to find a way to create a file that stores changes made to a folder and all files within it.

I have the path of the two folders I am comparing and the name of the output file. I need use these inputs to display files added or removed as well as lines added, removed or changed within the folder and store it in the file. The files in the folder are all text files.

Once this update has been changed I would also like to be able to use it to undo the changes made.

### Example:

#### Folder 1

foo1.txt

1. This is some text in the file

foo2.txt

1. This file also has some text
2. This file has two lines of text

#### Folder 2

foo2.txt

1. There is some text missing in this file

#### Output file

1. foo1.txt added
2. foo2.txt line 1 changed
3. foo2.txt line 2 removed

Comment: You're trying to recreate a revision control system. Why not use an existing one?

Comment: Use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to trigger a git add and commit when you have a file closed after creation or writes, a git rm and commit after deletes, &c. and you're done.

Comment: ...in general, btw, "please implement a thing for me that meets these specs" is too broad a question to be a fit for StackOverflow. Questions about specific problems that come up during your own intent at implementation are closer to proper scope.

Comment: Sound like an `scm` why not try git command to achieve that.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for your comments. This is my first question so I appreciate the advice. As for why I am making my own it is my task for uni. However I am new to bash so I was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction of a command that does what I want. The diff command I am currently using does not seem to work how I want or I am to incompetent.

Comment: Well -- showing what you're currently trying and how its behavior differs from what you intend would be a big move towards having a question that clearly *is* in-scope. :)

Comment: By the way, there's a historical revision control system that did store revisions as diffs, and early prototypes were implemented as shell scripts (though I got involved later, after a rewrite to C) -- one could certainly reconstruct repo contents using nothing but a shell and standard UNIX tools; you might find reviewing its storage format and/or source code interesting for context.  This is [GNU Arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_arch)